# Exclude field value from Total Grouping issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-grouping

in my report there is 3 parts:

Placement from a dataset

Processed from another dataset

Unprocessed is the difference between Placement and Processed.

The report is working fine and the grouping is perfect.

However i want only when the Type is "Proportional Treaty", Unprocessed PRemium and Brokerage should be equal to Zero instead of the difference between both.

i put the expression

```
=iif(Fields!Contract_Cover_Type.Value="Proportional Treaty",0,ReportItems!Textbox195.Value-ReportItems!Textbox198.Value)
```

and it worked only when grouping is "Proportional treaty"

Totals per month and Total at the end are Calculating the difference between Placement and Processed while it shouldnt include while deducting the Total of "Proportional Treaty".
Kindly advise

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to paste a simplified version of your DataSet with some sample data, along with your desired results? Enough to build a test example, basically. This would make it much easier to look at your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have three different types of totals. Each one is in a different grouping scope. Because of this, the expression will be different. In your situation, it would actually be much easier to add calculated fields to the dataset instead of trying to craft an elaborate expression for the conditional totals.

Go to your Dataset Properties. Go to Fields. Click Add then Calculated Field. Add fields for Unprocessed Number, Premium, and Brokerage. Use the expression here to determine if it will be 0 or not.

Now you can simply refer to these fields in the table. Your totals would look like

```
=sum(Fields!Unprocessed_Number.Value)
```

This will aggregate correctly for each of the 3 different "total" scopes because they are pre-calculated line-by-line.